# JavaFX beans/properites and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I must say that I'm new to Java and JavaFX (less than 2 months), and also my UML skills are not perfect, so I might have used wrong blocks or/and connectors on the diagram :) But I hope you get an idea.

I have an order management app with a following (simplified to essentials) design:

[OMS app design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUEsg.png)

Put very simply, the JavaFX GUI displays in a table view what is happening (i.e. the current state of the orders) between the client (that sends orders) and the broker (on the other end of the network connection). Order Manager is the only entity that has access to modify the model (i.e., the list of orders and their fields), and all methods modifying the model are synchronised (so it's safe to call them from any thread).

The orders are JavaFX beans, with different fields implemented as JavaFX Properties. These properties are bound to table columns in the GUI, so whenever the Order Manager updates a field, the change is propagated to the GUI via the binding mechanism.

Now, because the property binding mechanism is not thread-safe (see the following [rule](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> An application must attach nodes to a Scene, and modify nodes that are already attached to a Scene, on the JavaFX Application Thread.

), I have to wrap all the code modifying those fields, in Platform.runLater() calls, for example:

```
public void onOrderCanceled(int id, String reason) {
    Order order = orderbook.get(id);
    if(order == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Order "+id+ " not found");
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        order.setReason(reason);
        order.setStated(CANCELED);

        subscribers.foreach(sub -> sub.notifyUpdated(order));
    });
}
```

This approach has the following unpleasant implications:

1. The client notification is delayed by an arbitrary time (till the GUI thread finishes processing its message queue). Reason: I cannot notify the client before the order fields are updated (or it will have incorrect data), and I can only update the fields in the GUI thread.
2. Because the state of the order is not modified right away but at some future point, there exists for some time an incoherence between the order object and the actual order state.
3. If the GUI thread gets blocked or becomes very slow (because of bugs or design flaws), the client code is blocked or slowed down (while waiting for the notification that is stuck in the GUI thread's message queue).

Is there a better way of doing that? Ideally, I would like a solution that:

- Allows the client code to communicate with the networking layer (via the order manager) as fast as possible, i.e. without waiting for the GUI to catch-up
- The GUI is allowed to lag behind a little bit, but must not "skip" field updates, or at least never drop the most recent update (which is the most relevant)
- Rely on the FX property binding architecture to update the GUI (which I find very convenient)

I feel that I need to create another "model" for the GUI that will be updated in the FX thread only, while the "real" model will be used by the order manager and the client code, and I need to ensure to maintain the two models in sync (which is creepy).

Was FX designed without multithreading in mind? I had a look on the Task and Service interfaces, but is doesn't look like something appropriate (in my case, GUI doesn't initiates a task - it comes from an external source, the client code or the network).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain how the Task or Service classes are not helpful?

Comment: @JSamir because Task is designed to model a long async operation that runs in the background and returns a result. In my case, the app is just sitting and waiting for external events most of the time. Note that communication with the broker is not a strict request-response, there might be "responses" (notifications) without any request. I might be dumb, but I just don't see how to apply it here, what to encapsulate as a task...

Comment: When you say that that the application is waiting for external events, how does these external events and your application interact?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha There are two types of events: message from the broker (that is processed by a dedicated networking thread that calls a method of the order manager in the end), and an action from the client code (which runs in a separate thread and calls a method of the order manager when some condition is satisfied)

Comment: What does `sub.notifyUpdated(order);` do? I'm guessing it is notifying a client. As far as I understand it, you don't actually need to do that on the UI thread, you just need to ensure that the same updates happen as happen on the UI, and in the same order, is that correct?

Comment: @James_D That is correct. I do it on the GUI thread to be sure the client is not notified before all the fields are updated.

Comment: @Denis Tasks don't necessarily need a result. What is your broker (network connectivity) actually doing? And why is your order manager synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this implementation correctly, you are performing the notification to remote clients on the FX Application Thread. You're doing this because you need to send the clients the updated version of the `Order` object, and since this object is bound to the table, changes to its state can only happen on that thread.

This is somewhat perilous, as those remote notifications may take time, and so you may block the UI thread, causing a lack of responsiveness. Additionally, you are forcing the logic of the application to wait for the (potentially blocked) UI thread. This is the opposite way around to the way you should be doing things: your application logic should flow in a thread of execution in a natural way, and you should arrange for the FX Application Thread to show the latest version of the data in as lightweight a way as possible on each frame rendering.

I think what you need here is a separate, immutable class to represent the updates. You'll send those to your clients, and then on successful notification update the UI, instead of driving the application from the UI. So something like

```
public abstract class Update {

    private final int orderId ;

    public Update(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId ;
    }

    public abstract void performUpdate(Order order) ;

    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId ;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Cancelation extends Update {

    private final String reason ;

    public Cancelation(int orderId, String reason) {
        super(orderId);
        this.reason = reason ;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason ;
    }

    @Override
    public void performUpdate(Order order) {
        if (order.getId() != getOrderId()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong order");
        }
        order.setReason(reason);
        order.setState(CANCELED);
    }
}
```

Now in your application code you can do something like

```
public void onOrderCanceled(int id, String reason) {
    Order order = orderbook.get(id);
    if(order == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Order "+id+ " not found");
    }
    Task<Update> updateTask = new Task<Update>() {
        @Override
        public Update call() throws Exception {
            Update update = new Cancelation(id, reason);
            subscribers.forEach(sub -> sub.notifyUpdate(update));
            return update ;
        }
    };
    updateTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> updateTask.getValue().performUpdate(order));
    updateTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
        Exception exc = updateTask.getException();
        // handle exception
    });
    subscriberNotification.execute(updateTask);
}
```

Now you schedule updates in an executor dedicated to that particular functionality, and then update the UI when you know the notification has happened. In other words, the UI responds to the application logic, instead of the other way around. Your clients now receive the details of the update, and presumably they have their own representation of the `Order` (perhaps instances of the same class), and can update their own representations using the information in the `Update`. Note this will likely save you network traffic too (probably the biggest bottleneck in your application), because you only communicate the changes, instead of the entire object. Of course, this might entail some major refactoring of your code (sorry about that...).

It's going to be important that the updates are all transmitted in the correct order, so you should use a single thread of execution for managing them. In other words, you need something like

```
private final Executor subscriberNotification = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();
```

Comment: Thanks! I would definitely follow your advice if my clients were remote, but (so far) they are running as a part of the same application (sorry for not being enough clear on that). That means among other that they might retain references to the Order object (with read-only access). And what I wanted to avoid is specifically to have different representations of the same entity (i.e. order) in different pars of the program (in the order manager and in the client code).

Comment: If they have references to the same object, then why do you need the `notifyUpdated` call at all? Can't they just observe the JavaFX properties?

Comment: Well, they could indeed. Let's say this callback is just a convenience method (to avoid them listening on 10+ properties and figuring out what's happening from changes in individual fields). So ok, I can get rid of it. BUT this doesn't solve the initial problem, namely that the notification trigger (modifying property) happens in the GUI thread, does it?

Comment: Hmm. In that case I don't really see that there is a problem to worry about. As long as you ensure consistency, which your code does, and as long as you don't perform any long-running operation on the UI thread, which it sounds like you don't, then I think you are fine. I suppose the only issue that might be a concern is if you were scheduling `Platform.runLater()` tasks faster than they could be performed, but again unless you are doing something computationally expensive, that should not be the case.

Comment: Well, my main concern was as I'm new to GUI programming and JavaFX, I can do something stupid in the GUI thread that would consume a lot of CPU and will slow down the code that does not care about GUI at all... You partly reassured me, thank you for that :) But still it's somewhat contre-intuitive for me to have to update the model on the GUI thread, and make all users wait until it's done...

Comment: It's a price you're paying for sharing the actual entities between the GUI and non-GUI code. You might find you want to refactor that at some point, so that you have a service with notification to observers, one of which is your GUI model (serving only as the model for the GUI). Obviously there you gain some threading flexibility (threading issues are managed in the interface between the GUI model and the service) but you lose the convenience of the single data representation in memory. If you can make it work the way you have it, it's easier, but bear in mind you may need to refactor later.